# Adding 'Key:Value' in Multidimensional Dictionary is Overwriting

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I declared and initialized a `[[String:[String:String]` dictionary. It's empty in the beginning, and I am trying to add multiple values under the parent keys.

```
var dictionary = [String:[String:String]

// some checks

dictionary[i] = ["name" : name]
dictionary[i] = ["from" : country]
dictionary[i] = ["age" : age]
```

When I do that, I end up having only age key as a child under `[key: [String:String]`. So it's overwriting when I use this approach.

What is the appropriate way of doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is creating a new dictionary on each line and assigning this in the `dictionary` for key `i`, so you end up with the last dictionary `["age" : age]`

You need to create an inner dictionary, assign the values to this and then assign this to your outer dictionary;

```
var innerDict = [String:String]()
innerDict["name"] = name
innerDict["from"] = from
innerDict["age"] = age

dictionary[i] = innerDict
```

I would suggest, however, that you look at creating a Struct and put that in your outer dictionary rather than using a dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: This was the best approach for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
func insert(key:String, value:String, at k:String) {
    var d = dictionary[k] ?? [String:String]()
    d[key] = value
    dictionary[k] = d
}
```

And here's how to test it:

```
insert("name", value: name, at: i)
insert("from", value: country, at: i)
insert("age", value: age, at: i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *optional chaining* to assign to the inner dictionary, but you need to create the inner dictionary first.

```
// create the dictionary of dictionaries
var dictionary = [String:[String:String]]()

// some example constants to make your code work    
let i = "abc"
let name = "Fred"
let country = "USA"
let age = "28"

// Use nil coalescing operator ?? to create    
// dictionary[i] if it doesn't already exist
dictionary[i] = dictionary[i] ?? [:]

// Use optional chaining to assign to inner dictionary
dictionary[i]?["name"] = name
dictionary[i]?["from"] = country
dictionary[i]?["age"] = age

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

> ```
> ["abc": ["age": "28", "from": "USA", "name": "Fred"]]
> ```

---

Using these techniques, here's my version of @matt's `insert(_:value:at:)` function:

```
func insert(key:String, value:String, at k:String) {
    dictionary[k] = dictionary[k] ?? [:]
    dictionary[k]?[key] = value
}
```